# Need to "inject" @ApplicationScoped bean into Liferay hook

Tags: liferay-6

Both the managed bean and the hook are in the same war. I'm using 6.1 CE on Tomcat 7.

I'm trying to remove some data from the ApplicationScoped bean during the run method of a Hook tied to logout.events.pre.

The run method is called with an HttpServletRequest, and I've read that the bean should be accessible as an attribute of that HttpServletRequest or alternatively of the ServletContext I can get from the HttpServletRequest, but both methods return null.

I've enumerated all keys, and it's just not there.

Does anyone know how to acheive what I need?

Thanks.

```
    @Override
public void run(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse res) {

    System.out.println("In custom pre LogoutAction....");

    ServletContext servletContext = req.getServletContext();
```

//      DataBean dataBean = (DataBean) servletContext.getAttribute("com.xvest.hooks.DataBean");

//      DataBean dataBean = (DataBean) req.getAttribute("dataBean");

```
    // Find loggedInUser and impersonatedUser.
    ThemeDisplay themeDisplay = (ThemeDisplay) req.getAttribute("THEME_DISPLAY");

    User loggedInUser = themeDisplay.getRealUser();
    User impersonatedUser = themeDisplay.getUser();

    // Fetch CompleterHousehold for impersonatedUser.
    CompleterHousehold completerHousehold = dataBean.fetch(impersonatedUser, loggedInUser);

    // Delete loggedInUser from CompleteHousehold.viewers
    boolean result = completerHousehold.deleteViewer(loggedInUser);

    // If the delete returns true, there are no more viewers for this household, so delete the CompleterHousehold from DataBean.
    if (result)
        dataBean.delete(impersonatedUser);
}
```

Comment: It would be really helpful if you can provide some code to explain your requirement.

Comment: Here is the whole overriden run method. If you'll take note of the two commented out statements, you'll see I've tried two ways to access my @ApplicationScoped bean. I've also tried various variations of the bean name, but also printed attribute enumerations to the console and haven't seen it.<br />

Comment: The code has been added to my original question.